# Loading arm-shared-libs in Marmalade SDK

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, marmalade

Marmalade SDK supports making projects to generate arm-shared-libs. It also supports loading "libraries" via its s3eLibraryOpen(). However these seem to only be able to open x86 PE images that can also be generated with Marmalade SDK, but obviously as soon as I get a symbol and try calling the function it will crash since it's x86 and the calling process is ARM.

So just to re-iterate, the question is: Is there any support in Marmalade SDK for dynamically loading arm shared libraries at runtime?

Comment: should have asked on marmalade answers...

Comment: I would except I saw that many answers are left unanswered

Comment: Same in marmalade's own answer site. But at least you'll have more chances there.

Answer (score 0):

s3eLibraryOpen will allow you to load dynamic libraries on platforms that support it as as well as the dynamic library built for that platform Android (.so),Windows(.dll) , IOS does not support it.

Comment: So even though when I launch the emulator and it only works if the shared lib image is an x86 PE, if I would build the loading program for android, this call would expect an ARM ELF .so?